# TFS allow some users just to view the work items and queries

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I am using TFS 2015. I make one user as Readers in project settings but still the user is able to create and update work-items/bugs. So, I am confused what I need to do in order to allow a user to just view the work-items/quires/stories but not add/edit any item.

Answer (score 4):

The **Readers** group setting does not restrict ability to edit or create work items. You can do that in area path security settings [Set permissions and access for work tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/set-permissions-access-work-tracking). So you may create new group (in example **Disallow Access Group**). Then open security setting for the root area.

[image]

Deny needed permissions

[image]

In your case you have to enable **View work items in this node**

Answer (score 1):

If you have the user only in the Readers TFS group of the given team project, the user will not be able to able to add/edit work items.

This can happen if you have altered the group membership, so that Readers are member of the Team (the team created by default or a new team), which is default a member of  Contributors. This way readers TFS Group get inherited from Contributors permissions.

Verify the Readers group has below as permissions (default)

[image]

and it is **not** something like below
[image]

**The other possibility** is your user has collection level permissions so the project permissions are inherited to allow by default.

Comment: Interesting by default it allows readers to create work item, nothing is disabled.